# Suspend/Resume SQL database mirroring by C#

Tags: c#, t-sql, database-mirroring, windows-task-scheduler

I want to implement a Windows Scheduler job which suspense/resume the database mirroring sessions on a fixed period. Is this able to use C# code sending T-SQL query to suspense/resume mirroring sessions?

Comment: Yes. Use the same commands that you use with SSMS. If you use the UI only, click on the `Script` button that appears at the top of all dialog boxes to retrieve the SQL statement

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if you used SQL Server Agent to execute SQL commands directly instead of Windows Task Scheduler to run an application that would still run the same commands?

Comment: It's a good option. I will take it into consideration since the scenario is a little bit complicated. I need to actively push the transaction logs into a database and do mirroring this database to another server. Asynchronous database mirroring not allowed. Network shared folder is not allowed between 2 servers so I cannot use transaction log shipping purely. A little tip trick

Comment: You don't need asynchronous mirroring for this. You only need it if you need to mirror from one datacenter to another. *Why* don't you just allow synchronous database mirroring to work as intended? Did you try it and found a problem or just assumed you may have a problem?

Comment: You should also note that db mirroring is *obsolete*. It's been replaced by AlwaysOn.

Comment: Yes I know it. Since the SQL version is 2012 standard so no AlwaysOn

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos pls write your solution so I can mark it as answer